# How to succinctly recycle case_when LHS variables for subsetting/indexing using cbind?

Tags: r, dplyr

Example data:

```
tmp_df <- 
    data.frame(x_coord = c(3,4), y_coord = c(3, 3))
# x_coord y_coord
# 1       3       3
# 2       4       3
```

Consider the following which works as expected:

```
tmp_df %>%
    mutate(lin_ind = case_when((x_coord < 4 & y_coord < 4) ~ 
                                   x_coord + y_coord,
                               T ~ 0))
# x_coord y_coord lin_ind
# 1       3       3       6
# 2       4       3       0
```

Now, let me use `x_coord` and `y_coord` to index into a `3x3` matrix:

```
tmp_df %>%
    mutate(lin_ind = case_when((x_coord < 4 & y_coord < 4) ~ 
                                   matrix(1:9, nrow = 3)[cbind(x_coord, 
                                                               y_coord)],
                               T ~ NA_integer_)
    )
# Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
#     Evaluation error: subscript out of bounds.
```

This fails, for some reason the `cbind` part still takes a column index greater than 3.

This is a work-around that produces the expected result when `tmp_df` has this special form (i.e. two rows):

```
tmp_df %>%
    mutate(lin_ind = case_when((x_coord < 4 & y_coord < 4) ~ 
                                   matrix(1:9, nrow = 3)[cbind(x_coord[(x_coord < 4 & y_coord < 4)], 
                                                               y_coord[(x_coord < 4 & y_coord < 4)])],
                               T ~ NA_integer_)
    )
# x_coord y_coord lin_ind
# 1       3       3       9
# 2       4       3      NA
```

I cannot help but to think I am missing something with how `case_when` works.

The work-around also completely fails when `tmp_df` is more complicated:

```
tmp_df <- 
    data.frame(x_coord = c(3,4, 3), y_coord = c(3, 3, 3))
```

i.e. when there are just three rows:

```
> tmp_df %>%
+     mutate(lin_ind = case_when((x_coord < 4 & y_coord < 4) ~ 
+                                    matrix(1:9, nrow = 3)[cbind(x_coord[(x_coord < 4 & y_coord < 4)], 
+                                                                y_coord[(x_coord < 4 & y_coord < 4)])],
+                                T ~ NA_integer_)
+     )
Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Evaluation error: `(x_coord < 4 & y_coord < 4) ~ matrix(1:9, nrow = 3)[cbind(x_coord[(x_coord < 
    4 & y_coord < 4)], y_coord[(x_coord < 4 & y_coord < 4)])]` must be length 3 or one, not 2.
```

Here is a work-around for the more complicated data frame that produces the expected result:

```
tmp_df %>%
    mutate(lin_ind = case_when((x_coord < 4 & y_coord < 4) ~ 
                                   matrix(1:9, nrow = 3)[cbind(pmin(x_coord, 3), 
                                                               pmin(y_coord, 3))],
                               T ~ NA_integer_)
    )
# x_coord y_coord lin_ind
# 1       3       3       9
# 2       4       3      NA
# 3       3       3       9
```

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding what it is you wan to achieve. Can you provide and example of the desired output?

Comment: the work-around is an example in the case where the data frame only has two rows (very simple example). Basically, use `x_coord` and `y_coord` to index into a 3x3 matrix if both indices are valid, otherwise return `NA`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about replacing the indices outside of the boundary before extracting the matrix by them? While this is basically the same as your workaround, I think you don't need `case_when()` here.

```r
reprex::reprex_info()
#> Created by the reprex package v0.1.1.9000 on 2017-11-18

library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)

tmp_df <- 
  data.frame(x_coord = c(3,4, 3), y_coord = c(3, 3, 3))

tmp_df %>%
  mutate(
    mtrx_ind_x = if_else(x_coord < 4, x_coord, NA_real_),
    mtrx_ind_y = if_else(y_coord < 4, y_coord, NA_real_),
    lin_ind = matrix(1:9, nrow = 3)[cbind(mtrx_ind_x, mtrx_ind_y)]
  ) %>%
  select(- starts_with("mtrx_ind"))
#>   x_coord y_coord lin_ind
#> 1       3       3       9
#> 2       4       3      NA
#> 3       3       3       9
```

I guess what you are missing about `case_when()` is that the arguments are evaluated at once, not per row. For example, the code bellow does **NOT** paste `x[c(2,4,6,8,10)]` with `"px"`, but paste whole `x` and subset it by `c(2,4,6,8,10)`.

```r
x <- 1:10

case_when(
  x %% 2 == 0 ~ paste0(x, "px"),
  TRUE        ~ x
)
```

Does my explanation make sense?

Comment: thanks. Isn't this sub-optimal then? (Having to evaluate all rows, then take the subsets).

Comment: Ah, no. In terms of performance, your work-around version seems faster than mine...

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, I think a good way to solve this is with one of `purrr`'s map functions. Here you can iterative over `x_coord` and `y_coord` together and return an integer vector with `map2_int`. You can write a simple anonymous function (here done with the short `~` syntax) to apply to each set of `x_coord` and `y_coord`.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

df <- data.frame(x_coord = c(3,4, 3), y_coord = c(3, 3, 3))
mat <- matrix(1:9, nrow = 3)

df %>% 
  mutate(
    lin_ind = map2_int(x_coord, y_coord, ~{
      if (.x < 4 && .y < 4) {
        mat[cbind(.x, .y)]
      } else {
        NA_integer_
      }
    })
  )

#>   x_coord y_coord lin_ind
#> 1       3       3       9
#> 2       4       3      NA
#> 3       3       3       9
```

Comment: hmm, this is new and exciting, but I am not sure whether it is very succinct. It also doesn't explain what I am missing about `case_when`.