# Using complex RHS expressions in `dplyr::case_when()` in the context of `dplyr::mutate()`

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyeval, nse

## Problem

I'm trying to use `dplyr::mutate()` and `dplyr::case_when()` to create a new column of data in a dataframe that is populated using data stored in another object (a "lookup list") and is based on information in columns in the dataframe.

I know the answer probably has to do with (im)proper use of quasiquotation and NSE, but I'm having trouble extrapolating the information in the [Programming with `dplyr` vignette](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html) to my situation.

I'm hoping that posting this reprex here can guide me to the right answer, and I think that solving this problem will go a long ways towards helping me grok NSE.

## Sample data

```r
key_list <- list(
  "a" = list(
    foo = 1,
    bar = 2),
  "b" = list(
    foo = 3,
    bar = 4),
  "c" = list(
    foo = 5,
    bar = 6)
  )

x <- tibble(fruit = c("apple", "orange", "grape", "apple", "apple", "orange"),
            `Old Letter` = c("a", "a", "b", "c", "c", "c"),
            `Old Number` = c(9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4)
            )

x

# # A tibble: 6 x 3
#   fruit  `Old Letter` `Old Number`
#   <chr>  <chr>               <dbl>
# 1 apple  a                       9
# 2 orange a                       8
# 3 grape  b                       7
# 4 apple  c                       6
# 5 apple  c                       5
# 6 orange c                       4
```

## Goal

Specifically, I want to create a new column in `x` (which I will call `` `New Number` ``) that is populated based on the values in `x$fruit` and `` x$`Old Letter` ``.

Here's the code that mimicks where I get hung up in my actual use case:

```r
x %>% mutate(`New Number` = case_when(
  fruit == "apple" ~ pluck(key_list, `Old Letter`, "foo") * 10,
  fruit == "orange" ~ pluck(key_list, `Old Letter`, "foo") * 100,
  fruit == "grape" ~ pluck(key_list, `Old Letter`, "foo") * 1000
  ))

# Error: Index 1 must have length 1, not 6
```

## Expected output

In my mind, I see the (desired) order of operations like this, for e.g. the first row of `x`:

- `fruit == "apple"` is TRUE, so evaluate this expression: `` pluck(key_list, `Old Letter`, "foo") * 10 ``
- Since the value in the `` `Old Letter` `` column for this row is `"a"`, the expression becomes `pluck(key_list, "a", "foo") * 10` (which should operate on the `key_list` object in the global environment)
- This simplifies to `2 * 10` which equals `20`
- Place the result of evaluating this expression into the `` `New Number` `` column.

Extrapolating this to the entire command, I expected this as the output:

```r
# # A tibble: 6 x 4
#   fruit  `Old Letter` `Old Number` `New Number`
#   <chr>  <chr>               <dbl>        <dbl>
# 1 apple  a                       9           20
# 2 orange a                       8          200
# 3 grape  b                       7         4000
# 4 apple  c                       6           60
# 5 apple  c                       5           60
# 6 orange c                       4          600
```

## My take:

Judging from the error message I'm getting, it looks like rather than a single value from the `` `Old Letter` `` column being used as an index for `pluck()` to use, the entire `` `Old Letter` `` column is being passed as a vector. I'm guessing that this is because according to the [documentation for `case_when()`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/case_when.html):

> `case_when()` is not a tidy eval function.

I've tried to track down how this is happening, but the trace stack didn't seem to point me anywhere helpful, and wrapping the whole command in either `rlang::qq_show()` or `quo()` didn't show me how R was interpreting the command with respect to NSE because they both threw that same error as well.

I've experimented with combinations of:

- `quo()`,
- `enquo()`,
- `!!`,
- `!!enquo()` (shortened as `{{}}`), and
- `sym()`

in the `Reprex` code above, as well as wrapping it up into a function, but it throws the same error:

```r
get_num <- function(x, y) purrr::pluck(key_list, x, y)

x %>% mutate(`New Number` = case_when(
  fruit == "apple" ~ get_num(`Old Letter`, "foo") * 10,
  fruit == "orange" ~ get_num(`Old Letter`, "foo") * 100,
  fruit == "grape" ~ get_num(`Old Letter`, "foo") * 1000
  ))

# Error: Index 1 must have length 1, not 6
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47367377/5534515) to another question on SO tells me that

> I guess what you are missing about `case_when()` is that the arguments are evaluated at once, not per row.

But I'm not sure if/how that applies to my situation, so I'm at a loss.

Anyways, thanks for any help you folks can provide!

---

## `sessionInfo()`:

```r
R version 3.6.0 (2019-04-26)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS  10.15

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] rlang_0.4.1     readxl_1.3.1    forcats_0.4.0   stringr_1.4.0   dplyr_0.8.3     purrr_0.3.3     readr_1.3.1     tidyr_1.0.0     tibble_2.1.3   
[10] ggplot2_3.2.1   tidyverse_1.2.1

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.2       cellranger_1.1.0 pillar_1.4.2     compiler_3.6.0   base64enc_0.1-3  tools_3.6.0      digest_0.6.22    zeallot_0.1.0    evaluate_0.14   
[10] lubridate_1.7.4  jsonlite_1.6     lifecycle_0.1.0  nlme_3.1-141     gtable_0.3.0     lattice_0.20-38  pkgconfig_2.0.3  cli_1.1.0        rstudioapi_0.10 
[19] yaml_2.2.0       haven_2.1.1      xfun_0.10        withr_2.1.2      xml2_1.2.2       httr_1.4.1       knitr_1.25       generics_0.0.2   vctrs_0.2.0     
[28] hms_0.5.1        grid_3.6.0       tidyselect_0.2.5 glue_1.3.1       R6_2.4.0         fansi_0.4.0      rmarkdown_1.16   modelr_0.1.5     magrittr_1.5    
[37] htmltools_0.4.0  backports_1.1.5  scales_1.0.0     rvest_0.3.4      assertthat_0.2.1 colorspace_1.4-1 utf8_1.1.4       stringi_1.4.3    lazyeval_0.2.2  
[46] munsell_0.5.0    broom_0.5.2      crayon_1.3.4
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the issue may have less to do with NSE than the fact that `pluck` is not vectorized - as currently written `pluck` is not evaluated once per row, but rather all rows are attempted to be run through `pluck` at once. However, as you figured out, `pluck` needs a single number input, not a vector.

One way to solve this is to `map` the function across the rows, using your code as a little lambda-style function. Note that you need to use `map_dbl` to coerce a numeric value, otherwise `map` would return a list and everything would explode :-)

```
x %>% 
  mutate(`New Number` = case_when(
    fruit == "apple" ~ map_dbl(`Old Letter`, ~ pluck(key_list, ., "foo")) * 10,
    fruit == "orange" ~ map_dbl(`Old Letter`, ~ pluck(key_list, ., "foo")) * 100,
    fruit == "grape" ~ map_dbl(`Old Letter`, ~ pluck(key_list, ., "foo")) * 1000
  ))

# # A tibble: 6 x 4
#   fruit  `Old Letter` `Old Number` `New Number`
#   <chr>  <chr>               <dbl>        <dbl>
# 1 apple  a                       9           10
# 2 orange a                       8          100
# 3 grape  b                       7         3000
# 4 apple  c                       6           50
# 5 apple  c                       5           50
# 6 orange c                       4          500
```